# sum 12 months from specific date sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sum yearly records like `4th april 2001` to `4th april 2002` for every year in SQL.

Like:

```
Total | Year
2000  | 4th april 2001 to 4th april 2002
3000  | 4th april 2002 to 4th april 2003
```

and so on...

Comment: Stack Overflow is _not_ a service to write code for you. What have you tried so far? What does your existing code look like?

Comment: please put the table definitions and sample data too.

Comment: @AbeerUzZaman Please post your code to the actual question instead of adding it to the comments.

Comment: I have solved it by myself, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky.  I think the simplest way is to subtract 3 months and 3 days and aggregate by year:

```
select year((dte - interval 3 day) - interval 3 month), sum(amount)
from t
group by year((dte - interval 3 day) - interval 3 month);
```

Unfortunately, the existence of leap years interferes with a calculation by day, because in some years February has 28 days and in others 29.